# mysql: return only 4 rows with same cat_id

Tags: mysql

I have one table:

```
items
item_id|cat_id|name
1      |2     |item_1
2      |2     |item_2
3      |1     |item_3
4      |3     |item_4
5      |2     |item_5
6      |3     |item_6
```

I wrote this query:

SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_id IN (2,3);

How can I  return **at most/at least** 4 rows for both cat_id's (resulting in **at most/at least** 8 rows)?

Comment: Why is the `cats` table relevant to this question? The query only uses `items`.

Comment: In hindsight I guess it was redundant to show the cats table. Hopefully it doesn't confuse..

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve this? Al the previous suggestions have not been successful..

Comment: If the answer from m4573r isn't successful then you're not describing the problem correctly. It should work.

Comment: His answer just displays 4 results, not 4 results for both cat_id's. I tried to be more specific in the problem description. Hopefully it helps..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

m4573r was close: Here's the correct SQL:

```
(SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_id = 2 LIMIT 4)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_id = 3 LIMIT 4);
```

Without the parentheses, the LIMIT at the end applied to the union, not the subquery.

Answer (score 3):

```
(SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_id = 2 LIMIT 4)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_id = 3 LIMIT 4);
```

Comment: You misunderstood me. I need max 4 results for both 2 and 3. This just returns 4 results

Comment: Thanks. Would this query be slow if there were many cat_id's?

Comment: Not really, if you have an index on `cat_id`... just annoying to write.

Comment: Ok, so if there where 20 cat_id's and the items table had 2-3 million lines this would still work pretty fast, you think?

Comment: It depends on your hardware, and on what you define by "pretty fast", but in my experience (and of course providing you have an index on `cat_id`, this is capital), it would work pretty fast.

Comment: i just checked the query and it only returned 4 results with cat_id 2 and then when I raised the limit to 8 it returned 8 results with 2? ..it didn't display 4 with 2 and 4 with 3

Comment: The `UNION` operator just concatenates results from queries. If you copy pasted my 3 lines and still had only 4 results, it means that you don't have any record with cat_id = 3

Answer (score -1):

Easier :

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_id = (2,3) LIMIT 4;
```

Done

Comment: I just got an error with this on: Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Show me more of the code maybe you didn't introduce SQL with the right syntax.

Comment: So try this : SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_id = 2 LIMIT 4;

Comment: then SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_id = 3 LIMIT 4;

Comment: Change `=` to `IN` in the answer.

Comment: @SamiKhoury: The OP asked for a limit of 4 `per` cat_id, so in the case of `2` and `3` the most it should return is 4 per id and 8 in total. So, even when using `IN (2, 3)` you are limiting to 4 in total. Increasing this to 8 is also not going to work as the requirement is to get a maximum of 4 `per` `cat_id` and with `(2, 3)` you could end up with 6 from one and 2 from another for example.